# How do I create nano-scale mesh electronics in Solidworks?

Tags: cad, solidworks

I'm trying to complete a project for my solidworks course and it involves nanoelectronics. The idea is to create a mesh array of field effect transistors (FETs) that will monitor the firing of neurons in a microfluidic device. My design is inspired by science articles like this one:
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6528/ab3534

I've already had some problems with using Solidworks for nano-groove technology as 72k features is too much for my computer to handle, but there won't be a need for as many nanotubes and circuits for the mesh. I can make a 3D image of what I want, but my professor wants me to make an electrical simulation to verify my design works. My professor is also not too available to me at the moment, so I'm limited on asking him what to do.

There's no need to worry about how I will shape and orient the nano-scale wires. I just need to know how I would build a new electronic part from scratch. If I just make copper and carbon tubes, is that going to be enough to properly simulate?

Here are some images to help clarify what I want to make:
[image: FET image]
[image: Mesh Electronics]
[image: Mesh Electronics]
[image: Mesh Circuits]

Comment: "To properly simulate" - Simulate *what*? How it behaves electrically? mechanically? I'm not sure SolidWorks is the best tool for electrical simulation...

Comment: @Jonathan R Swift electrically is what concerns me at the moment.